# How to debounce SearchBar in NativeScript Angular?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to debounce the search input:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

    onTextChanged(args) {
        let searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;

        if (searchBar.text) {
            this.updateResults(searchBar.text);
        } else {
            this.results = new ObservableArray();
        }
    }

    updateResults(q) {
        // hit api
    }
}


<SearchBar (textChange)="onTextChanged($event)"></SearchBar>
```

As is the backend will be hit on every keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FromControl and add `debounceTime` operator at `valueChanges` subscription. Make sure you import the `ReactiveFormsModule` too.

**HTML**

```
<SearchBar [formControl]="searchControl" class="input"></SearchBar>
```

**TS**

```
this.subscription = this.searchControl.valueChanges
        .pipe(debounceTime(500))
        .subscribe((value) => {
            console.log(value);
        });
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=jmzL5a)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this for SearchBar in nativescript.

**HTML:-**

```
<SearchBar class="form-input search-barHead" [text]="searchPhrase" 
(loaded)="searchBarLoaded($event)"
  textFieldHintColor="#ffffff" textFieldBackgroundColor="#02637E" height="40" 
  hint="Search TCP" (clear)="onAllSearchClear($event)" (submit)="onAllSearchSubmit($event)">
```

**Typescript:-**

```
Public searchPhrase:any;

public searchBarLoaded(args) {
    let searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;
    if (searchBar.android) {
        searchBar.android.clearFocus();
    }
}

public onAllSearchClear(args) {
    let searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;
    let searchProduct = searchBar.text;
}

public onAllSearchSubmit(args) {
    let searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;
    let searchProduct = searchBar.text;
}
```